# How to delete matrix elements where the conditions apply to more than one dimensional element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix

```
m={{10,2},{20,3},{30,4},{40,5},{50,6}}
```

I can find certain elements with this statement

```
list=Select[m,(10 < #[[1]] < 50 ) && (#[[2]] < 6) &]
```

and I get

```
{20,3},{30,4},{40,5}
```

How can I use DeleteCases to remove the items {10,2} and {50,6}? I know I can invert the logic on the Select case, but I'd like learn to use DeleteCases, but can't figure out the right syntax for the selection. A one dimensional list is more straight forward, but I'm having trouble generalizing to higher dimensions.

Also, can anyone point me to clear documentation on selection syntax, as I am only mimicing the syntax I see in working examples and that often doesn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[m , _?(Not[10 < #[[1]] < 50 && #[[2]] < 6] &)]
```

> `{{20, 3}, {30, 4}, {40, 5}}`

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear just what criteria you're seeking.  It is easy to "remove the first and last items" by `Delete[m, 1]` and `Delete[m, -1]` or

```
Delete[m, {{1}, {-1}}].
```

What mathematical criteria do you wish to invoke?

Comment: What you offer is also useful, but I was looking for deleting certain elements which meet certain criteria. The fact that the selected items were the 1st and last items was just a coincidence. I will modify my original question